# If domain A has an iframe of domain B, which has an iframe of domain A, can domain A access the cookies of domain B?

Tags: html, security, iframe, cross-domain

I remember reading about domain A being able to control domain B if domain B has a helper frame inside it. I have pages like StumbleUpon, where I place other websites in iframes. What if one of those websites place my page in an iframe? Also, stuff like Facebook's Like button and Twitter's Tweet button are all iframes. What data would/woudn't that have access to?
Would they be able to inject scripts into my page?

Comment: The use of iframes has no effect on the cookie SOP model. However, you may want to consider how to address `clickjacking` attacks if your site can be iframed in to someone else's. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, they can not access other domains cookie.

No matter where you hide an iframe with different domain, browser will always send cookies that were set for that specific domain.

Like button can be created utilizing `Referer` header.

Say, `http://domainA.com/index.html` contains

```
 <iframe src="http://domainB.com/like.html"></iframe>
```

Here when `http://domainB.com/like.html` is called inside the iframe an HTTP header `Referer: http://domainA.com/index.html` is sent along with the request. This way `domainB.com/like.html` always knows who is requesting. When `domainB.com` got this little piece for information it can just check the number of likes of the page and show the result.

#### A live example

Put the bellow code in any of your websites. After that every time you refresh the the website it'll show how many times its loaded. It'll count the number of hits.

```
 <p>This page is viewd 
 <iframe 
      src="http://tools.cmyweb.net/hitcounter.php" 
      frameborder="0" 
      scrolling="no" 
      width="40px" 
      height="16px" 
 />1</iframe> times</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your site can't access another domain in an iframe, and that other domain can't access your site. However, if the iframe is under the same domain as the parent, it can be accessed via javascript.

Read more here: http://pipwerks.com/2008/11/30/iframes-and-cross-domain-security-part-2/

Edit: Here's some more good reading http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy

Edit2: Regarding your questions about Facebook Like button etc. That depends on how you add the like button to your page. If you add it via a inline javascript that javascript will have access to everything on your site. However if its just an iframe inserted into the document it won't have access to anything on your page

Answer (score 1):

No, the [Same-Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) forbids the access: Unless the two documents have the same origin (basically same protocol, host, and port number in URL), scripts running in origin cannot access another document’s DOM unless it’s in the same origin.

But those ‘social plugins’ are often embedded by loading an external script from their servers. In that case the foreign script is loaded and then executed in the origin of your page. So the Same-Origin Policy does not apply. In that case those scripts would be able to access any cookie that is accessible by JavaScript (i. e. no *HttpOnly* flag).

Answer (score 0):

This would not solve your problem. Just because they have an iframe of your site embedded doesn't mean your site has any greater access to cookies, scripts, etc in the other site.